# What instances are there in which two species share the same binomial name?

Tags: taxonomy, nomenclature

Since binomials are required to be unique only within a kingdom, two species can share the same binomial name if they are in different kingdoms. I know of one instance of this, *Orestias elegans*: this name denotes [a species of fish](https://species.wikimedia.org/wiki/Orestias_(Cyprinodontidae)_elegans) (kingdom Animalia) as well as [a species of orchid](https://species.wikimedia.org/wiki/Orestias_(Orchidaceae)_elegans) (kingdom Plantae).

Are there other instances where one binomial name validly refers to two (or more!) species?

Comment: This is a fascinating and surprising tidbit of information that practically begs to be used as the point of a puzzle story.

Comment: But why on earth did anyone think it would be a good idea to allow such a thing?

Answer (score 15):

There are four other instances of species-level hemihomonyms I can find:

1. *Agathis montana* can be either a critically endangered species of [conifer](https://www.google.ca/search?q=Agathis+montana&rlz=1C1CHWA_enCA608CA608&oq=Agathis+montana&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i59j69i60l3.865j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) or a parasitic [insect](http://animaldiversity.org/accounts/Agathis_montana/classification/).
2. *Centropogon australis* can be either a [fish](https://www.google.ca/search?q=Centropogon+australis&rlz=1C1CHWA_enCA608CA608&oq=Centropogon+australis&aqs=chrome..69i57.1102j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) or a plant with a long red [flower](http://davesgarden.com/guides/pf/go/199584/).
3. *Asterina gibbosa* can be either a [sea star](http://www.habitas.org.uk/marinelife/species.asp?item=ZB1130) or a type of [fungus](https://ncim.nci.nih.gov/ncimbrowser/ConceptReport.jsp?dictionary=NCI%20Metathesaurus&code=C3539522)
4. *Baileya australis* can be a [moth](http://mothphotographersgroup.msstate.edu/species.php?hodges=8973) or a yellow flowering [plant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baileya_multiradiata)

Comment: Deep in the Binomial Nomenclature [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_nomenclature#cite_note-18) citations!

Comment: The "wiki citations!" link in the previous note was a (now broken) indirect reference to [https://species.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Species-level_hemihomonyms](https://species.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Species-level_hemihomonyms) ,

Comment: Looking for hemihomonyms here: http://www.irmng.org/homonyms.php

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the five listed above, Wikipedia currently shows two others, for a total of seven:

*Ficus variegata* can be either a sea snail or a fig

*Tritonia pallida* can be either a nudibranch or an iris

See "Hemihomonyms" [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homonym_(biology)#Hemihomonyms).

Answer (score 2):

Two others for posterity, since I haven't seen others bring it up. Rhaphidophora is a genus of flowering plants AND of cave crickets, and there are two species-level hemihomonyms. R. beccarii is an uncommon houseplant and its relative R. neglecta is much rarer, but both are still documented. There's hardly any record that the cave crickets with these names exist, but they [both seem to be accepted species with type specimens and all.](http://orthoptera.speciesfile.org/Common/basic/Taxa.aspx?TaxonNameID=1129905) I looked hard for images of either one and came up empty handed.

Comment: Very nice first post, welcome to Biology. Please take our [tour] and refer to the [help] for guidance as and when, enjoy the site.