# There are plants and animal genera with the same Latin name. What are the scopes of uniqueness?

Tags: terminology, taxonomy

The genus *Leptochilus* occurs as a genus of wasps, and of a genus of ferns.

What are the parts of the phylogenetic tree where uniqueness is required, and how many of them are they?

(Where can I read about this, without reading all the individual standards?)

Ref: https://www.inaturalist.org/observations/154939850

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What instances are there in which two species share the same binomial name?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/58075/what-instances-are-there-in-which-two-species-share-the-same-binomial-name)

Comment: Thank you! Yet no. If the person who asks is correct, an alternative formulation of my question is: What kingdoms exist with respect to nomenclature?
Obviously plants and animals, but what about fungi - different from animals as witnessed by Asterina gibbosa, but are they among the plants? What about diaphoretickes? Bacteria? Viruses? I only find special articles, no overview.
Ah, and I assume that uniqueness is already at genus level, not binomial. (Both is interesting of course.)

Comment: @Falko https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kingdom_(biology)

Comment: Ups. Diaphoretickes contains plants of course. I intended to mention Stramenopiles.

Comment: @BryanKrause Yes, so we have n kingdoms, where n = 2 ... 8 :-)

Comment: @Falko there are few instances where a systematist might confuse an animal with a plant etc., so uniqueness should only need to extend to kingdom.

Comment: Here https://biology.stackexchange.com/a/73452/63850 Karl Kjer mentions, that animals, plants, and bacteria have their own independent nomenclatural codes. This seems to settle it. (I'm still reading though.)