# Are All Taxonomic Groups Uniquely Named?

Tags: taxonomy, nomenclature, classification

The Linnaean classification system classifies and groups organisms into taxonomic groups: Kingdom, Phylum, Class, etc. Obviously, a clade at any taxonomic level is uniquely determined by its classification at this level and all its parents in the hierarchy, e.g., Kingdom = *Bacteria*, Phylum = *Firmicutes*, Class = *Clostridia* uniquely identifies a group of bacteria. But is this group also uniquely identified by just *Clostridia*? Or are there situations where two Phylums might both contain Classes with the same name?

Since Genus & Species are typically used to identify organisms, I would assume that combinations of these at least are unique. As @Jam pointed out in the comments, Species alone is not enough. Note, however, that I am *not* asking about the binomial name for a species - I am asking about uniqueness among higher levels of aggregation, such as Class, Order, and Family.

Comment: The simple answer to your question is 'no' because many species share the name 'vulgaris'. But whether all genuses and classes are uniquely named, I'm not sure.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How many species can have the same scientific name?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/73421/how-many-species-can-have-the-same-scientific-name) and [What instances are there in which two species share the same binomial name?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/58075/what-instances-are-there-in-which-two-species-share-the-same-binomial-name)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What instances are there in which two species share the same binomial name?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/58075/what-instances-are-there-in-which-two-species-share-the-same-binomial-name)

Comment: Duplicate voters: note OP has now made explicit that the question is only about taxon rank higher than species.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are quite a few [biological homonyms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homonym_(biology)) (especially at the genus level, which apparently you aren't asking about).  At the family taxonomic level, the Interim Register of Marine and Nonmarine Genera (IRMNG) [currently lists 100 family names](http://www.irmng.org/homonyms.php?tRank=140) which are used for two or more distinct taxa.

Comment: Are there any homonyms between taxa above family rank: classes, phyla, types?