# What does the word specific epithet mean?

Tags: botany, nomenclature

Is the species for *Rosa indica* and *Mangifera indica* 'indica' as you can see is the same in both. What does this signify. It is obvious that it has different species as they have different genus.

Comment: See the last line of my answer [here](https://biology.stackexchange.com/a/78929/42697).

Comment: Thank You @NatWH that cleared things up nicely.